# Simple menu in IOS - (objective-c or swift)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, menu

Im trying to understand how does the mobile development works. I want to do a common view to different views. My idea is to make a menu... but i cant manage to make it work properly. 
Explaining it fast would be, as i said, a view created in my Storyboard that i can call, programatically, from any view that i want. I want to be able to move around without warnings. 
Should i use UINavigationViewController?
This is the custom menu i want to create :

[image: Image view of menu that i call]
[image: When i press on the arrow (or orange part) i open the menu and i can go anywhere i want]

Answer (score 3):

Yes you should use a `UINavigationController`. If you drag one out in StoryBoard, it will automatically make the first child, a `UITableViewController`, which is what you picture above.

There's still a lot you need to know to put all the pieces together but that's how you start, and use a tutorial like this to come up with a more specific question that won't get downvoted. :-)

http://www.appcoda.com/use-storyboards-to-build-navigation-controller-and-table-view/